# Junit test with powermock gives initialization error via eclipse but runs through command line

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, powermock

When I run a particular test case file with power mock via eclipse I get below error but with command line I am fine. Also I am able to run other test files without power mock in it via eclipse.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Error is :-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.paychex.mobile.remote.ReportingMobileRemoteTest. Reason: Invalid index
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:214)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:144)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:138)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:858)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:765)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:735)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:146)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1002)
    at java.lang.Class.getResource(Class.java:2074)
    at javassist.ClassClassPath.find(ClassClassPath.java:85)
    at javassist.ClassPoolTail.find(ClassPoolTail.java:354)
    at javassist.ClassPool.find(ClassPool.java:590)
    at javassist.ClassPool.createCtClass(ClassPool.java:574)
    at javassist.ClassPool.get0(ClassPool.java:539)
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:447)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass0(MemberResolver.java:477)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:409)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupFieldByJvmName2(MemberResolver.java:274)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess2(TypeChecker.java:887)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess(TypeChecker.java:844)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atFieldRead(TypeChecker.java:777)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atExpr(TypeChecker.java:578)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Expr.accept(Expr.java:68)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess(TypeChecker.java:834)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atFieldRead(TypeChecker.java:777)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atExpr(TypeChecker.java:578)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Expr.accept(Expr.java:68)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:660)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atDeclarator(CodeGen.java:726)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Declarator.accept(Declarator.java:100)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:569)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:754)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.modifyMethod(MainMockTransformer.java:206)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfStaticAndFinalAndNativeMethods(MainMockTransformer.java:142)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:65)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:210)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same error, using PowerMock and JUnit 4. Any help will be appreciated, all that I found online is not working.